# pre-process Acceleremeter data for analysis

Tags: android, android-sensors, data-analysis

I would like to do accelerometer data analysis and possible with other sensor data as well for activity recognition (e.g. driving). But before proceeding to activity recognition I guess I will need to do some pre processing.

I came across on some research paper that they had used high pass filter, low pass filter, fft and etc to pre process the data.

Can anyone explain what is high pass filter, low pass filter, fft on sensor data analysis? I have search that online but is still unable to understand the what it is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

Google actually already does this, you can use their code.  I can explain those terms to you, but if you don't know them you're months of study away from being able to do this at best.  I suggest using Google's detectors.

Basic analysis-  every jostle of an accelerometer causes a wave.  THese waves have varying frequency.  You examine them via frequency domain analysis

High pass filter-  a filter that allows through high frequency waves but eliminates low frequency ones

Low pass filter-  a filter that allows through low frequency waves but eliminates high frequency ones.

FFT-  fast fourier transform.  A Fourier transform transforms a signal into an infinite series of sine and cosine waves that sum into the original signal.  FFT is an algorithm for figuring out the coefficients of those sines and cosines.  Its used in frequency domain analysis.  As stated by the name, its a fast way of doing it without using formal integrals (the usual way to do it by hand is to calculate the integral of f(x)e^(-ix) where i is the square root of -1 and f(x) is the signal data.

Answer (score 0):

High pass filters are used to find high frequency data. Low pass filters are used to find low frequency data. FFT is used to find the strength of the signal in each frequency band. Based on these you can determine information as well as isolate information you know is there. For example, with a low pass filter, you can normally find the gravity vector. For example fi you are on a vibrating car, the vibrations will be in high frequency and gravity is a very very low frequency. The specific technique about isolating gravity is explained pretty well in the Android [documentation for sensors and motion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html). In that case they use an [exponential moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average). The high pass filter then isolates the very short term movements of the car, in the highest frequency you get engine and road noise, as well as the electrical noise of the sensor itself (in a typical quality of Android device you'll see some noise). Exponential average (and FIR filters in general) are popular here because they are easy to compute.

Low pass filter is also good to find steering activity, if that's what you are looking for, especially if you can find a way to isolate it from gravity (i.e. by assuming a particular orientation of the device, you can low pass filter on the plane parallel to the ground).

FFT makes more sense to apply if you are wanting to get really detailed. If you want to find a very specific signal or you know what you are looking for, you might know it creates vibrations at a certain frequency. For that you can use FFT to isolate all frequencies at once to get anything you want. But FFT takes a lot more CPU horsepower, which in a mobile device also means reduced battery life.